# unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"' and unexpected end of file errror

Tags: bash

I searched a lot of similar error on Bash_Profile, but no one seems to look like mine.. I'm on macOS Sierra 10.12.6 and this is my Bash_Profile

[My Bash_Profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xVOh.png)

I always get the messages, no matter what I do, not even deleting the lines, rebooting, the error is just transferred to another line.

[The error messages I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6Io4.png)

Please, could someone point me what is going on?

Comment: That looks like a stray/missing quote. The first error message should give the line where that quote starts, but of course the actual error could be earlier (the quotes will just mismatch). But please don't post text as images, it makes it harder for others to read, and _especially_ to modify for debugging! Instead, see the [editing help](https://serverfault.com/editing-help) and use the code block formatting.

Comment: [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) might be able to spot the problem.

Comment: Stupid "smart quotes" strike again.

Comment: Please paste the actual contents of your bash profile and error messages as text here, not screenshots.

Answer (score 4):

The first quote on CFLAGS_FORGA is curly. The second is straight.

[image]

Replace the curvy one with a straight one.

There are various places you've used curly quotes. Replace them all with straight ones.